# Understanding the concept vanishing gradient and exploding gradient problem in terms of training data

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, gradient-descent

I'm trying to figure out the essence of the concepts "vanishing gradient and exploding gradient problem" in terms of real-world input-output training examples instead of in terms of the properties of the choice of activation function.

Can anybody direct to a good tutorial that include such examples?

Answer (score 0):

I always refer "Andrew NG" documents if available for any ML understanding. I believe that Youtube link [Vanishing and Exploding Gradient](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhXZsFVxGKo), will help you in understanding the concept in a better way.

**Still a brief from my side:**

> DNN of K layers without an activation function, will be like
>   multiplying K coefficients(weights) together. Somehow if you received
>   initial coefficient **value < 0**, in such a case during back
>   propagation till you reach to the starting layers (from Input layer
>   side), it may possible you completely lost the value of gradient,
>   as gradually you are multiplying smaller value i.e. vanishing a value. Similarly if initial
>   coefficient **value > 0**, multiplying together will form a very big
>   number i.e. exploding a value.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to understand and intuitively comprehend the concept of vanishing gradients and exploding gradient would be through manually solve through a backpropagation.
Since, Feed Forward Neural Network is simplest of all and Mostly sigmoid function and Tanh suffers from vanishing gradient .
It would be wise to build a MLP with at least one hidden layer and compute the change in parameter values after forward pass , error calculation and backward pass to update weights and biases initialized randomly.
https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/

Likewise, RNN are mostly suffering from exploding gradient you could apply same method.

It may seems far fetched to go to this trouble for understanding concepts , but it is worth your time.

Answer (score 0):

At high level, you can think of vanishing gradients in the way Chinese whispers work: Part of the original information is being lost every time it is being passed backwards to another person. In a similar way, RNN architecture "looses" part of the original information of a gradient as it is being propagated from the very last time step backwards to the very first step.

Drilling down to the specifics see below:

### Vanishing gradients

Traditional Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) have the ability to model sequential events by propagating through time, i.e. forward and backward propagation. RNN models connect each time-step (e.g. position of a word in a sentence) using the following function defined as hidden state:

$a_n = f(W_n, a_{n-1}, x_n)$

The hidden state $a_n$ carries past information by applying a linear combination over the previous step and the current input.

The issue with the above is that the hidden state of every current position is a function of *all previous positions*. This means when you backpropagate gradients through time (see BPTT) the gradient inherently "looses" part of its "amplitude" because of the chain rule in $a_n$:

$a_n = f(W_n, a_{n-1}, x_n) = f(W_n, f(W_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, x_{n-1}), x_n)$, since $ a_{n-1}=f(W_n, a_{n-2}, x_n)$.

In this way, the longer the input sequence is  the worse *long terms dependencies* will be captured to to the way gradients vanish because of the chain rule in their hidden state.

I hope it helps. See here my relevant post in case it may also be of help https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/84409/102852